# Beam / DataFlow unexpected error ProtocolMessageEnum not implemented when using DataFlowRunner

Tags: protocol-buffers, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, dataflow

When running my Beam pipeline locally it all works as expected but when trying to run it on the DataflowRunner I suddenly get the error below. Honestly I don't even know where to start evaluating this because the DataflowRunner seems to be a black box.

```
Jan 14, 2019 11:26:51 AM org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.DataflowRunner fromOptions
INFO: PipelineOptions.filesToStage was not specified. Defaulting to files from the classpath: will stage 165 files. Enable logging at DEBUG level to see which files will be staged.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Class org.apache.beam.model.pipeline.v1.RunnerApi$StandardPTransforms$Primitives does not implement the requested interface com.google.protobuf.ProtocolMessageEnum
        at org.apache.beam.runners.core.construction.BeamUrns.getUrn(BeamUrns.java:27)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.core.construction.PTransformTranslation.<clinit>(PTransformTranslation.java:58)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.core.construction.UnconsumedReads$1.visitValue(UnconsumedReads.java:49)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy$Node.visit(TransformHierarchy.java:666)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy$Node.visit(TransformHierarchy.java:649)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy$Node.visit(TransformHierarchy.java:649)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy$Node.visit(TransformHierarchy.java:649)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy$Node.access$600(TransformHierarchy.java:311)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy.visit(TransformHierarchy.java:245)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.traverseTopologically(Pipeline.java:458)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.core.construction.UnconsumedReads.ensureAllReadsConsumed(UnconsumedReads.java:40)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.DataflowRunner.replaceTransforms(DataflowRunner.java:868)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.DataflowRunner.run(DataflowRunner.java:660)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.DataflowRunner.run(DataflowRunner.java:173)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.run(Pipeline.java:313)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.run(Pipeline.java:299)
        at (my code: pipe.run().waitUntilFinish();)
```

Comment: Can you post the command line you're using? Check the pipeline options doc for dataflow runner, you may be missing something: https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/specifying-exec-params (e.g. filesToStage)

Comment: Another potential reason something like this could happen if you used unsupported characters in pipeline options, e.g. colons in the job name. Try using alphanumerics if you are doing something like that.

Answer (score 0):

check the versions of beam etc and upgrade your dependencies where possible.

I had the same error and after seeing you get this error, I thought it must be a dependency conflict as it didn't exist before.

I'm using scio to deploy to dataflow and just referenced what they're using. https://github.com/spotify/scio/blob/v0.7.1/build.sbt
I updated guava and protobuf also.

I know you're using java, but try updating beam to 2.9.0 and maybe guava, protobuf...